# Enhance UI Responsiveness in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, tablelayoutpanel, openaccess

I have created an POS application using Dynamic buttons, dynamic table layouts, and other controls in one form. The generated dynamic buttons is based on the number of data queried from the database(using OPEN ACCESS ORM).

My problem is whenever I run the application, the UI responsiveness is slow. For Example when I click on a category button, the sub category buttons appears (These are dynamic generated buttons), for it to appear, it would take few seconds to appear, then there are some little flash on the screen.

What will I do? What strategy should I perform.

Thank you. So much

Comment: It depends on your code.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the buttons do not have time consuming actions. And if they do:

- use a waitcursor (simple solution, but not liked by most users)
- use a thread to perform the action (might complicate other actions regarding thread safety).

Comment: You shouldn't use Thread class directly, it's too lowlevel and error-prone. Use TPL instead with async/await features or without them.